# Whats the surface area of the surface $0 \leq z, (x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, manifolds

Whats the surface area of the manifold $0 \leq z, (x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1$?
The surface is the intersection of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ and a cylinder centered at $(1,0,0)$. I'm just not sure how to parameterisize the surface and then calculate the volume.

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: I don't quite get the notation $0 \leq z, (x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1$.  To me that means $0 \leq z\le 1$ and $0\le (x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1$, i.e., a (solid) cylinder of radius 1 and height 1.  I do not see where $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ comes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems most straightforward if you parameterize in cylidrical coordinates. Then along the surface,
$x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2+z^2=4$, so $z=\sqrt{4-r^2}$, and
$$\vec r=\langle r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,\sqrt{4-r^2}\rangle$$
$$d\vec r=\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta,\frac{-r}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}\rangle dr+
\langle -r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,0\rangle d\theta$$
So the vector areal element is
$$\begin{align}d^2\vec A & =\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta,\frac{-r}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}\rangle dr\times
\langle -r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,0\rangle d\theta\\
 & =\pm\langle\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}\cos\theta,\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}\sin\theta,r\rangle dr\,d\theta\end{align}$$
And the scalar areal element is
$$d^2A=||d^2\vec A||=\sqrt{\frac{r^4}{4-r^2}+r^2}dr\,d\theta=\frac{2r}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}dr\,d\theta$$
On the boundary of the area, $(x-1)^2+y^2=r^2-2r\cos\theta+1=1$, so $r=2\cos\theta$, and $-\frac{\pi}2\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}2$.
So now we can compute the area
$$\begin{align}A & =\int d^2A=\int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2}\int_0^{2\cos\theta}\frac{2r}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}dr\,d\theta\\
 & =\int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2}\left[-2\sqrt{4-r^2}\right]_0^{2\cos\theta}\,d\theta
=-2\int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2}\left(2|\sin\theta|-2\right)\,d\theta\\
 & =-8\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\left(\sin\theta-1\right)\,d\theta
=-8\left[-\cos\theta-\theta\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\\
 & =4\pi-8\end{align}$$
Now there is a little ambiguity here: Do you want the area of the cap or some more areas as well?